# How to uninstall serverless? "npm uninstall -g serverless" is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04, npm-install, serverless

I cannot uninstall serverless. I have tried `npm uninstall -g serverless` but entering `serverless -v` after prints the version. I'm on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Running `which serverless` prints `/usr/bin/serverless`.

I'm using n to have multiple versions of node installed so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: try `which serverless` to see the location you installed.

Comment: it prints `/usr/bin/serverless`

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps for different reasons I also wanted to remove global `serverless` and instead use a local version. Ultimately, regardless of installing `serverless` locally or globally, `serverless CLI` will still install serverless-components into your home directory.  I think the whole point of installing `serverless` locally would be to pin serverless-components at a specific version number.

More to your question, here's how to remove a global install `serverless` and replace it with a local version.

### Remove Globally Installed Serverless

Let's say you ran `npm install -g serverless` and you ran `npx serverless`. It has now installed any components listed in your `serverless.yml` file and updated your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

To remove it:

1. `npm uninstall -g serverless`
2. Open your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`) and remove the line

```
# Added by serverless binary installer
export PATH="$HOME/.serverless/bin:$PATH"
```

3. `rm -rf ~/.serverless`
4. `rm -rf ~/.serverlessrc`
5. `rm -rf ~/.serverlesscomponentsrc`

### Use Serverless locally

The [serverless-nextjs docs say](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js#getting-started):

> Do not add @sls-next/serverless-component to your package.json file, it is not used and only the version in serverless.yml file is used.

But, therein lies the problem, you want to use a `serverless-component` (like serverless-next.js) but serverless is going to install it globally in your home directory.

To avoid that you can ignore the docs and do:

1. `npm install serverless --save-dev`
2. `npm install @sls-next/serverless-component --save-dev`
3. Update `serverless.yml` to point directly to the component

```
# serverless.yml
nameOfMyApp:
 component: "./node_modules/@sls-next/serverless-component"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that you are not running a local version of serverless installed in the project directory.
2. Manually delete the binary with `rm -f /usb/bin/serverless`

Comment: also it's to check if there's any serverless process running, kill it before you delete the folder. I had it on mac and had same problem, but my installation was in ~/.serverless

Comment: Check location using `which serverless`. Mine was at /home/yourname/.serverless/bin/serverless in linux. Then try deleting

Answer (score 0):

Try npm run with --force to overwrite files

```
npm install -g serverless --force
```